Semidefinite program to compute Z-eigenvalues
I have a Hermitian matrix $H \in \mathbb{C}^{n^2 \times n^2}$ and I want to solve the following optimization problem.
$$\max_{v \in \mathbb{C}^n, \ v^\dagger v = 1} \ (v \otimes v)^\dagger H (v \otimes v)$$
From what I have read, this problem appears to be related to something called the $Z$-eigenvalue problem and the local optima appear to be to satisfy an eigenvalue equation.
$$ 1 \otimes v^\dagger H (v \otimes v) = \lambda v $$
Can my original quartic optimization problem over vectors $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$ be transformed into a linear semidefinite program over positive semidefinite matrices $X \in \mathbb{C}^{n^2 \times n^2}$? I suspect that it can, by optimizing over the convex set of all $X \in \mathbb{C}^{n^2 \times n^2}$ of the form $X = \sum_i p_i v_i v_i^\dagger \otimes v_i v_i^\dagger, p_i \geq 0$. The trouble is, I don't know how to write down a linear map that checks whether or not a given $X$ belongs to this convex set.
In other words, I suspect there is some linear, Hermiticity-preserving map $\Phi$ such that
$$\max_{v \in \mathbb{C}^n, \ v^\dagger v = 1} \ (v \otimes v)^\dagger H (v \otimes v) = \max_{X \in \mathbb{C}^{n^2 \times n^2}, X \succeq 0, \mathrm{Tr}[X] = 1, \Phi[X] = 0} \mathrm{Tr}[H X]$$,
but I'm not totally sure this is true and I'm at a loss for what exactly this map would be.
Thanks in advance!
